# APE engine Mysql push data to channel on insert

Tags: mysql, ajax, push, ape

I am working with APE Engine (http://www.ape-project.org) and up until now I had no actual problem.

The problem is that I would like to use the MySQL module and push data to a channel each time a row is inserted into a table.

I've tried to setup a server side module, I created an SQL query but data is fetched only when the server boots.

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

i tried posting the same topic on the official google group.

here's what i got: [Google Groups - Ape Project - Push data on insert](http://groups.google.com/group/ape-project/browse_thread/thread/a572863f00571d1a/de274866ee329bc2?lnk=gst&q=mysql+push+on+insert#de274866ee329bc2)

Hope that helps :)